# Batch file to copy files from one folder to another folder

Tags: batch-file, file-io

I have a storage folder on a network in which all users will store their active data on a server. Now that server is going to be replaced by a new one due to place problem so I need to copy sub folders files from the old server storage folder to new server storage folder. I have below ex:

from `\Oldeserver\storage\data & files`    to `\New server\storage\data & files`.

Comment: I assume you're talking about a Windows environment?

Comment: @pluma [Batch files are .bat. Yes, they only run on Windows.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file)

Comment: @HugoM.Zuleta, I'm aware of .bat files. But "batch file" is not necessarily guaranteeing a Windows environment. The use of the term pre-dates Windows (as do .bat files) and I've even seen novices use the term to mean "shell scripts" in *nix environments.

Comment: @pluma I agree, and this is mostly because they refer to batch operations done by their OS's scripting tools.

Answer (score 519):

**xcopy.exe** is definitely your friend here.
It's built into Windows, so its cost is nothing.

Just `xcopy /s c:\source d:\target`

You'd probably want to tweak a few things; some of the options we also add include these:

- `/s/e` - recursive copy, including copying empty directories.
- `/v` - add this to verify the copy against the original. slower, but for the paranoid.
- `/h` - copy system and hidden files.
- `/k` - copy read-only attributes along with files. otherwise, all files become read-write.
- `/x` - if you care about permissions, you might want `/o` or `/x`.
- `/y` - don't prompt before overwriting existing files.
- `/z` - if you think the copy might fail and you want to restart it, use this. It places a marker on each file as it copies, so you can rerun the xcopy command to pick up from where it left off.

If you think the xcopy might fail partway through (like when you are copying over a flaky network connection), or that you have to stop it and want to continue it later, you can use `xcopy /s/z c:\source d:\target`.

Comment: @Iavinio It's asking file or directory when copying an archive. Is there a way to suppress that ?

Comment: Hi @mini-me - I found that if it's a directory, you can specify a trailing '/' character and you won't see that message.

Comment: `/i` - If destination does not exist and copying more than one file, assumes that destination must be a directory.

Comment: How to copy a single file from the directory?

Comment: To get around the "file or directory" prompt, do the command like so...     `echo f | xcopy /s /f srcfile destfile`

Comment: How to make sure the Xcopy doesn't copy an incomplete file. I mean while another program is coping the file (when its not ready), can Xcopy hold until its finished?

Comment: @Salindaw did you got any answer to your query?

Comment: `xcopy /s /y c:\source d:\target` add y for overwriting without stopping the script

Comment: If you don't want to be bothered by xcopy question about copying a file or a directory, just add * at the end of the file to copy by default as a file (plus, /y to overwrite destination)
`xcopy /Y C:\file.txt C:\myfold\file.txt*`

Answer (score 83):

My favorite one to backup data is:

```
ROBOCOPY "C:\folder" "C:\new_folder" /mir
```

/mir is for mirror. You can also use /mov to move files. It reproduce the exact same folder. It can delete/overwrite files as needed. Works great for me. **It's way faster than xcopy / copy. It's built in Windows as well.**

Source: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx

Comment: I support this. It is really fast. much faster than xcopy

Comment: Is there a way to recursively remove thumbs.db similar to this?

Comment: Exactly the thing I was looking for. Copies all the subfolder and files exactly from source.

Answer (score 59):

Just to be clear, when you use `xcopy /s c:\source d:\target`, put "" around the c:\source and d:\target,otherwise you get error.

ie if there are spaces in the path ie if you have:

```
"C:\Some Folder\*.txt"
```

but not required if you have:

```
C:\SomeFolder\*.txt
```

Comment: The quotation marks made the trick ;) thanks
 I also used /Y to replace the file if it exists :) 
Example: ´´´xcopy /s "c:\source" "d:\target" /Y```

Answer (score 18):

To bypass the 'specify a file name or directory name on the target (F = file, D = directory)?' prompt with xcopy, you can do the following...

`echo f | xcopy /f /y srcfile destfile`

or for those of us just copying large substructures/folders:

use /i which specifies destination must be a directory if copying more than one file

Comment: (echo "f" for files or "D" for directories)

Comment: trying to do this now and it just aint working - I always get prompts when trying to copy one file to another directory. Using Win 10 if that affects it at all
echo f | xcopy /f /y "My.dll" "C:\myFolder\My.dll". I've tried it with a combination of other switches to no avail (and capital F)

Answer (score 17):

You may want to take a look at [XCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/xcopy) or [RoboCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) which are pretty comprehensive solutions for nearly all file copy operations on Windows.

Comment: RoboCopy seems to be better than XCopy because xcopy asks for file or folder decisions. And I can't turn it down. It MUST be able to work full automatic.

Comment: @mini-me I know this is very late however I cant find the same relevant switch. I ended up resorting to making it create a blank file with the same name I am copying to and then overwrite it. If the file already exists then it doesnt bother asking if its a file or directory. (If you want auto directory then you can append a '/' to the path and it will do it). Hope this helps future people!

Comment: @Eve For reference, `echo f | xcopy source destination /y` will make it automatic.  It assigns all questions an "f" as a response.  It will also pass overwrite requests (f is taken as yes, I think).

Comment: [Difference between xcopy and robocopy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24121046)

Answer (score 11):

If you want to copy file not using absolute path, relative path in other words:

Don't forget to write backslash in the path AND NOT slash

Example:

```
copy children-folder\file.something .\other-children-folder
```

PS: absolute path can be retrieved using these wildcards called "batch parameters"

```
@echo off
echo %%~dp0 is "%~dp0"
echo %%0 is "%0"
echo %%~dpnx0 is "%~dpnx0"
echo %%~f1 is "%~f1"
echo %%~dp0%%~1 is "%~dp0%~1"
```

Check documentation here about copy: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490886.aspx

And also here for batch parameters documentation:
https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/percent.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: I think that \ is called backslash.

Answer (score 4):

```
@echo off

rem The * at the end of the destination file is to avoid File/Directory Internal Question.

rem You can do this for each especific file. (Make sure you already have permissions to the path)
xcopy /Y "\\Oldeserver\storage\data\MyFile01.txt" "\\New server\storage\data\MyFile01.txt"*
pause

rem You can use "copy" instead of "xcopy "for this example.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use esentutl  to copy (mainly big) files with a progress bar:

```
esentutl /y "my.file" /d "another.file" /o
```

the progress bar looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Look at `rsync` based Windows tool [NASBackup](http://www.nasbackup.com/index.php/Features). It will be a bonus if you are acquainted with rsync commands.

Answer (score -3):

For **Windows** Users

1. Create **copyfile.exe** OR **copyfile.cmd** OR **copyfile.bat**
2. Add this

```js
#!AutoCopy
xcopy /s C:\folder\from  C:\folder\to
```

3. Just open by double click **copyfile.exe**

OR open **cmd** type `copyfile.bat` press enter