# Batch: Copy files from txt file into one folder

Tags: batch-file, copy, xcopy

I am attempting to create a batch file to copy several files listed in a text file to a new folder. I have found several threads relating to this, but I can still not get the batch to work properly. The problem I am encountering is that the files listed in the txt are all in different source locations and have different extensions. The list reads, for example:

> C:\Users\Foo\Pictures\Photographs\September\P1030944.jpg
>   C:\Users\Foo\Videos\Art\Movies\Class\movie.avi
>   C:\Users\Foo\Music\Jazz\20051.mp3
>   ...etc

All the copy commands I could find have to list either the source directory i.e.

```
set src_folder=c:\whatever\
set dst_folder=c:\foo
for /f %%i in (File-list.txt) DO xcopy /S/E/U "%src_folder%\%%i" "%dst_folder%"
```

or the extension i.e.

```
for /R c:\source %f in (*.xml) do copy "%f" x:\destination\
```

but I need it to gather that information from the list itself.
If it helps I know that there are only files of a possible 39 different specific extensions in the txt (*.jpg *.gif *.png ... *.xhtml *.xht)

Any help/ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Batch file to copy files from one folder to another folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986447/batch-file-to-copy-files-from-one-folder-to-another-folder)

Answer (score 5):

Start reading `HELP FOR` and then try the following at the command prompt

```
FOR /F %a in (input.txt) DO @ECHO COPY %a c:\newfolder\%~nxa
```

you can see that `%a` gets expanded to the actual line in the input file, and that `%~nxa` is a way to extract the name and the extension from the file.

After careful testing, move the command to your BAT file, replace `%a` to`%%a`, and remove the `ECHO` command

```
@echo off
SET destfolder=c:\newfolder 
FOR /F "delims=" %%a IN (input.txt) DO COPY "%%a" "%destfolder%\%%~nxa"
```

notice the wraping of the names with quotes `"`; and the inclusion of the `"delims="` option; both are needed in case filenames contain blanks.

Finally be careful with possible name duplicates in the destination folder. If that is possible, you need to find an strategy to cope with such collisions. But this can be the subject of another SO question, can't it?

Comment: it will not work with entries containing spaces (but I would leave this as a task to OP - if your first point is followed, this should not be too difficult to solve :-)

Comment: Awesome, thanks PA! this works perfectly, had to a miniscule amount of tweaking but it does exactly what i needed. I guess I was lacking knowledge about the n and x modifiers that you explained above. Thanks again!

Comment: @wmz you are right, tomorrow I will edit my answer with the solution for the case the filenames in input.txt contain blanks

Comment: yeah, I noticed that it won't work with blanks, I just added blanks delims:  FOR /F "delims=" %%a IN (%CD%\archive.txt) DO COPY "%%a" "%destfolder%\%%~nxa"

Comment: I edited the answer to include the "delims=" option to completely solve the filenames with blanks problem.

Answer (score 0):

One sample which worked for me...

Replace my directories C:\whatever and C:\temp\svn with yours...

assuming that your filelist is named antidump_list.txt and located under C:\temp\svn\

```
> set src_folder=C:\whatever
> set dst_folder=C:\temp\svn
> for /f %%i in (C:\temp\svn\antidump_list.txt) DO copy "%src_folder%\%%i" "%dst_folder%\%%i"
```

Regards,

Gottfried

Answer (score -1):

I have found that the easiest way to do this is to use a powershell script.

```
$Files = Get-Content File-list.txt
$Dest = "C:\output"

foreach ($File in $Files) {
  Copy-Item $File $Dest
}
```

If you need to run it from a batch file, paste the above script to file named `CopyFiles.ps1` and add the following command to your batch file

```
powershell -executionpolicy bypass -file .\CopyFiles.ps1
```

Since, powershell is included by default on Windows7 and newer, this method is as easy as doing the same with batch commands only.

Comment: it copies all file in same folder not as in src directory

Comment: That is what OP wants. See the first line of the question. He is just trying to copy the files to `a new folder`