# Copy Resources while building project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, compilation, copy, building

How can I copy `Resources` subdirectory to `TargetDir` after `Build`?

I tried:

```
copy “$(ProjectDir)\Resources” “$(TargetDir)”
```

but this copy files, not directory

**EDIT**

```
xcopy /s “$(ProjectDir)\Resources” “$(TargetDir)”
```

gives the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
xcopy /ey "$(ProjectDir)CellEditing" "$(TargetDir)CellEditing\"
```

- The `/e` parameter is used to indicate recursive copy (including empty directories)
- The `/y` parameter is used so it overwrites files if you run it again
- Don't forget the trailing `\` at the end of the destination otherwise xcopy doesn't know whether you are specifying an output directory or an output file name.

See also [write a batch file to copy files from one folder to another folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986447/write-a-batch-file-to-copy-files-from-one-folder-to-another-folder)