# xcopy command in batch for usb flash drive

Tags: batch-file, hidden, xcopy

I want to create a `*.bat` file for copying computer files to a usb flash drive. I found an answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/986505/10595637).

It works but there is one problem. When it copies libraries like documents and pictures, it's ok, but when it copies local drives like drive **D**, it makes the target folder totally hidden. Even when hidden files are shown, the target folder is hidden and only solution is to search name of one of files in that folder.

Comment: This isn't a 'here is the code' type of site. Please edit your question to provide your code as you've modified it from the linked answer, and then explain with real examples of how the result differs from your intent or expectations.

Comment: Second what Compo says... I've used `xcopy` many times and not seen it do anything like what you describe, so please [edit] your question to include concrete examples of your code and "test data". Also useful would be what the address bar shows when you have found these hidden files, and the output of `dir /a` from a command-prompt at appropriate places. A final plea: when you add these details, please do so as copy-pasted text, formatted as _Code Sample_ (the `{ }` icon) and don't paste screen images.