# How to use python libraries in nodejs application

Tags: python, node.js

I have installed all the Node.js libraries as required for my nodejs application. But the nodejs application at the backend uses python libraries which has some lines of code such as `import nltk` and all other libraries. and these import statements when uploaded on a `heroku` platform is raising an error.

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "mainfile.py", line 2, in import functionfile as f File "/app/functionfile.py", line 1, in import nltk ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nltk'`

I have uploaded all the files but still it is raising an error.

complete code deployed on heroku is available in github link - https://github.com/rinku16/patranker

nodejs application code files is present in app folder

Issue: How can i use this nltk and other python libraries in my application.

Below are the python libraries required in the python file

```py
# Import function file as reference to use defined python functions
import functionfile as f
import sys 
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
#for generating sentence token
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
#for generating word token
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
# BeautifulSoup for scraping and Requests to make HTTP requests.
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
# BeautifulSoup is in bs4 package 
import requests
#Counter class For Getting Most Occurred Biwords
from collections import Counter
#FOR MAKING DATA FRAME AND WRITING THE PATENT EXTRACTED DATA TO CSV FILE
from pandas import DataFrame
import pandas as pd
import os
import os.path
from os import path
import re
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from datetime import date
import math
```

For example, for `nltk` library below is path of the file i got

```
>>> import nltk 
>>> nltk.__file__ 'C:\\Users\\Carthaginian\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\nltk\\__init__.py'
```

how i use this path to clone it in my nodejs application. please see this.

Comment: When i run this project in my localhost, it run smoothly becoz all python libraries required  in python code is available in my C drive of the system.

Comment: can it be done by git cloning of the python libraries available

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom_lib folder and clone all the libraries in it. Provide the correct path using import or require in Node.js project. Use [gulp](https://gulpjs.com/) runner or any task runner to copy these custom_lib to your build folder and remember follow the same hierarchy in the build folder structure.

You can also write a custom [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986447/batch-file-to-copy-files-from-one-folder-to-another-folder) to copy these python_lib to the build folder. You can add this custom script in package.json in scripts.

We have the same issue in our project and it work like a charm.

Comment: is it i have to clone from my local system or from some online repository of the python

Comment: i m actually just started using git, i used git for push, pull, commit and status only

Comment: please look at the directory structure of my project link - https://github.com/rinku16/patranker

Comment: Apoorva, i m not able to get with you answer, please can you help me in this

Comment: can you give example for `import nltk`

Comment: Create a Python REPO and clone the flies into it. Now, create a script to copy files in your node.js project in folder "python_libs". As you said it is running in your local system, try to change path from c drive to your "python_libs" folder. And run it on your local system. Once, it is done then you can create build and copy these file in www folder.

Comment: You need o have all dependencies for python modules too to make it run else It will throw errors again.

Comment: Hi, i got this path, `>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.__file__
'C:\\Users\\Carthaginian\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\nltk\\__init__.py'`

Comment: where in my system code for nltk is present

Comment: This is python dependency, I think you need to install python and its dependency on the server(Heroku environment) and then try to launch run Node.js app. It is natural language tool kit in python : https://pypi.org/project/nltk/

Comment: can you help me

Comment: You need to install and setup python env on heroku instance as it seems to work fine on local env. Try to setup the mirror image of your local.

Comment: This is not the question i have pasted new question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66914878/please-see-my-problem-believe-me-it-is-easy-to-solve

Comment: This one i m struggling a lot in this

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSPyBridge https://github.com/extremeheat/JSPyBridge (in readme there are plenty of examples)